# strtol is pointing to original string

Tags: c++, strtol

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
uint64_t descendingOrder(uint64_t a)
{
   string str = to_string(a);
   sort(str.begin(),str.end(),[](unsigned char a , unsigned char b) { return a>b;}); 

   cout<<"sorted string:" <<str<<endl;
   cout<<"value        :"<<strtol(str.c_str(),nullptr,10)<<endl;
   return strtol(str.c_str(),nullptr,10);
}

int main()
{
  descendingOrder(9223372036854775807L);
}
```

---

```
sorted string:9887777655433322200
value        :9223372036854775807
```

Why are the `sorted string:` and `value:` are different? It seems like `value:` took the original string somehow even after sorting. Where is the mistake? Is it UB?

Code: [Online code](https://onlinegdb.com/Ac8Qq-zxy)

Comment: Use [`std::stoull(str)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) for **unsigned** long long instead. The `strtol` (and `std::stol` in C++) is for **signed** longs.

Comment: OT: Use `char` instead of `unsigned char` as `std::string` uses `char`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

9887777655433322200 is out of range for a `long` on your architecture.

That's why `errno` gets set to `ERANGE` and `LONG_MAX` (which happens to be your input) is returned. Note that an implementation may also use `LLONG_MIN` or `LLONG_MIN` or even `LONG_MIN`. You need to check `errno` in order to know whether the conversion with [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) worked.

If you used [`std::stol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) you would have ended up with an `std::out_of_range` exception instead. Whether you want to use exceptions is up to you, but meanwhile, use either [`std::strtoull`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) for `unsigned long long` (and check `errno`) or use [`std::stoull`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) (and keep possible exceptions in mind).

See `[string.conversions]` in the C++ standard or the links above to cppreference.com for more information.

Comment: [`std::from_chars()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) is also an option.